# Windows 8: how to add user control with C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I created an user control for my Windows 8 metro style app, I know how to add it to the page with XAML, but how to add it dynamically with C# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked it, but it should be the same as for WPF:

```
MyUserControl myControl = new MyUserControl();
myPanel.Children.Add(myControl);
```